# Telegram bot (pyTelegramBotAPI)

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

Здравствуйте уважаемые форумчане!
Подскажите как решить такую проблему:
Написал небольшой бот для телеграма, который регистрирует данные об автомобиле, введенные пользователем. Бот работает, но только когда пользователи вводят по очереди, а когда одновременно то введеные данные перезаписываются, к примеру:
юзер 1 вводит:

```
рег. номер - 123
марка - AUDI
модель - 100
```

юзер 2 вводит:

```
рег. номер - 456
марка - ВАЗ
модель - 2101
```

результат может быть:

```
рег. номер - 456
марка - AUDI
модель - 2101
```

сам код:

```
import telebot
import config
from time import sleep
from telebot.types import Message

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

markup_menu = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
btn_new = telebot.types.KeyboardButton('Запись нового авто')
btn_verify = telebot.types.KeyboardButton('Проверка авто')
markup_menu.add(btn_new, btn_verify)

car_plate = ''
car_make = ''
car_model = ''

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message: Message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Для начала нажмите необходимую кнопку', reply_markup=markup_menu)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def new_verify(message: Message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'запись нового авто':
        begin_new_car = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите регистрационный номер:')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(begin_new_car, get_car_plate)

def get_car_plate(message: Message):
    global car_plate
    car_plate = message.text.upper()
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите марку авто:')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_car_make)

def get_car_make(message: Message):
    global car_make
    car_make = message.text.upper()
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите модель авто:')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_car_model)

def get_car_model(message: Message):
    global car_model
    car_model = message.text.upper()

    res = """
    Р/Н: {}
    Марка: {}
    Модель: {}
    -----------\n\n"""
    with open('cars.txt', 'a', encoding='utf8') as car_file:
        car_file.write(res.format(car_plate, car_make, car_model))
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Записано!')

while True:
    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop = True)
    except:
        sleep(20)
```

Полагаю что перезаписываются данные в переменных. Получается что нужно для каждого юзера своя переменная, как-то так, не знаю.
Подскажите как решить данную проблему, может есть более подходящее решение.
Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 2):

Главным пунктом решения будет отказ от глобальных переменных. Лучше используйте БД, в `Python` встроена `sqlite3`.

Плохим решением, но все же решением будет использование глобального массива `cars = []`:

```
cars = []
@bot.message_handler(text=['запись нового авто'])
    def new_verify(message: Message):
        global cars
        t = []
        begin_new_car = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите регистрационный номер:')
        car_plate = message.text.upper()
        t.append(car_plate)

        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите марку авто:')
        car_make = message.text.upper()
        t.append(car_make)

        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите модель авто:')
        car_model = message.text.upper()
        t.append(car_model)

        cars.append(t)
```

Таким образом вы получите массив массивов с данными об автомобилях